# Preprocessor defines

Tags: c#, generics, c-preprocessor

Fairly straight forward question, is it possible to write a C# preprocessor directive so I can do the following? :

```
ClassZ<A, B, C, D, E, F>
```

to

```
ClassZ<T>
```

where

```
T = <A, B, C, D, E, F>
```

Comment: Could you provide more information as to why this is required?  We may be able to provide you a better solution without a preprocessor or class aliasing.

Comment: Unfortunately that's probably a question in its own (too big to contain here) as to why that structure is required. And specific questions like that with large descriptions that I've asked in the past tend to get ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. C# `#define` does not allow for macros or text replacements. It can only be used to define tokens for usage in `#if` directives.

Answer (score 6):

This is somewhat possible.

You can write

```
using ClassZT = ClassZ<A, B, C, D, E, F>;
```

Note that unless you put that inside your `namespace` block, you'll need to fully qualify every name.

However, you cannot make a parameter set the way you appear to be asking.

Comment: See creating an alias with the using directive - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx

Comment: You mean creating an alias to a namespace... which isn't what I'm doing.

Comment: @Ian: No; you can alias classes too, including generic parameterizations.

Comment: SLaks, unfortunately I can't do that because I have a hierarchy of derived classes, all of which have these rather larger generic declaration. But +1 because that detail wasn't in the question.

Comment: @Ian: Are you sure you can't? Why not?

Comment: @SLaks: Oh sorry, I didn't read properly. Yes I can do that bit, that's kinda a half way house I suppose. My ideal would be to remove my 6 generics to replace with <T> throughout my solution apart from the define, but yeah I can do what you've suggested per class.

Comment: You should rethink your design; classes with six generic parameters are rarely a good idea.

Comment: @SLaks: Thanks for the pointer. I'd generally agree, but I've looked at other approaches and unfortuantely I don't believe there are any other suitable ways to structure the assembly and keep the type safety that I require :(

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning on implmenting the preprocessor yourself there is no reason you can't... But C# (at least the standard Microsoft version) doesn't have preprocessor macros like C or C++